# Can CSS Grid layout be used to implement resizing of editor panes (e.g. as in CodePen)

Tags: css, css-grid

I'd like to implement resizable panes without JS, only using [CSS Grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid). Is this possible?

For e.g. CodePen's editor has resizable panes for its HTML / CSS / JS editors. Also, see the example below which implements it in plain JS (I can't seem to add a URL to the CodePen  example in it, so it's a bit hard to add attribution. The code is by http://codepen.io/gsound/).

```js
let isResizing = false;

let $handler = document.getElementById('handler');
let $wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
let $left = document.getElementById('left');

$handler.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
  isResizing = true;
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  if( !isResizing ) return;
  let newWidth = e.clientX - $wrapper.offsetLeft;
  $left.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
  isResizing = false;
});
```

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#app{
  height: 100%;
/*   max-width: 1400px; */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
  background-color: #AAA;
  height: 50px;
}

#wrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: flex;
}

#handler{
  background-color: red;
  width: 5px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

#left{
  width: 200px;
}

#content{
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}


/* ----------- */

#left{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#content{
  background-color: #232378;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <header>head</header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <aside id="left"></aside>
    <div id="handler"></div>
    <article id="content"></article>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S as a side note, I have re-implemented the e.g. above by adding and removing `'mousemove'`, `'mouseup'` events and was wondering whether that's "better" (more performant) than using a boolean `isResizing` and keeping the event listeners always there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grid Layout module is pure CSS.

Resizable panes generally require JavaScript to function.

Knowing that CSS is designed primarily for styling and presentation, there are most likely no built-in properties or methods in the [**Grid Layout spec**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/) that would provide for manually resizable panes.

Comment: Well, there is the `resize` property in CSS. But I haven't found a way to make it work well with CSS grid.